# For loop in Panda Dataframe with multiple conditions and different data types

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, types

I need help with this code:

```
d={'Name': ['Mark', 'Lala', "Nina", 'Catherine', 'Izzy', 'Ozno', 'Kim'],
    'Level' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'D', 'D'], 
    'Seats' : [3000, 5000, 4000, 1000, 1000, 2600, 2400]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

I want to add a new column called "Level_corrected", this is a duplicate of df['Level'], but if df['Level'] = 'D' and df['Seats'] <2500, than the 'D' value in df['Level_corrected'] will become 'D-'.

The desired result is:

```
d={'Name': ['Mark', 'Lala', "Nina", 'Catherine', 'Izzy', 'Ozno', 'Kim'],
            'Level' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'D', 'D'], 
            'Seats' : [3000, 5000, 4000, 1000, 1000, 2600, 2400],
            'Level_corrected': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D-', 'E', 'D', 'D-']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

I've done several attempts (I didn't save the code ...), but it seems like the error is because of the different data types. The Level column is an 'object' and the Seats column is a float64.

Could someone please help me?

Many thanks!

Comment: `df['Level'].mask(df['Level'].eq('D') & df['Seats'].lt(2500),'D-')`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with chained both masks with `&` for bitwise `AND` and compare by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for equal and [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) for less:

```
df['Level_corrected'] = df['Level'].mask(df['Level'].eq('D') & df['Seats'].lt(2500),  'D-')
print (df)
        Name Level  Seats Level_corrected
0       Mark     A   3000               A
1       Lala     B   5000               B
2       Nina     C   4000               C
3  Catherine     D   1000              D-
4       Izzy     E   1000               E
5       Ozno     D   2600               D
6        Kim     D   2400              D-
```